# Using string match to search a file

Tags: tcl

Want to search within a file using tcl to find a match.

Here is what I have.

```
set search "random string"
set file [open "file.txt" r]
 while {![eof $file]} {
    gets $file data
    if {[ string match [string toupper $search] [string toupper $data] ] } {
    //works
    } else {
    //doesnt work
    }
 }
```

File.txt

```
chicken.dinner:1439143130
random.strings:1439143130
more random strings:1439413390
random.strings.that.contain-special.characters:1439441566
```

Not able to match "random string" with what's in the file. Appreciate any help.

Comment: eof is seen directly after a read past the end of file, and this last read does not deliver data - you could look for idiomatic file read in wiki.tcl.tk.

Comment: See http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.tcl/fmm.html#eof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use only `string match`, then use the glob pattern `*` here.

```
set search "random string"
set file [open "file.txt" r]
 while {[gets $file data] != -1} {
    if {[string match *[string toupper $search]* [string toupper $data]] } {
        puts "Found '$search' in the line '$data'"
    } else {
        # does not match case here 
    }
 }
```

**Output :**

```
Found 'random string' in the line 'more random strings:1439413390'
```

Since we want to know whether the line contains the search string, we have added `*` at the beginning as well as in the end. It can match any number of sequence.

**Reference :**  [string match](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35)

Comment: Also, the `-nocase` option means that the match is case insensitive, alleviating the need to adjust text case.

Comment: I'd use `string index` with a simple comparison instead as the OP appears to have specified a *plain* (non-pattern) string in the question. I'm sure that's what everyone else would propose, too, but I don't see this mentioned.